# Where can I get higher resolution StackOverflow, ServerFault and SuperUser logos?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to get the site logos in printable quality or in vector graphics?

- [DeviantArt](http://digitaljackalnz.deviantart.com/art/omg-why-the-downvotes-109735716)
- [Meta Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/how-would-you-design-a-stackoverflow-t-shirt/7308#7308)

Comment: Why?

Comment: The SO gods might sue you. It is the American way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would email the team (Contact Us link at the bottom of the page) and explain why you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are always the originals from the [SO](http://99designs.com/contests/6774/entries/251), [SF](http://99designs.com/contests/20088/entries/184), and [SU](http://www.crowdspring.com/projects/graphic_design/logo/logo_for_superuser_com/gallery/6__1) logo competitions.  I don't know if anyone but the original logo creators have a higher-res version.

Comment: Would they be allowed to give it away? I don't think they would, but I'm no IP lawyer.

Comment: Using a logo can be considered fair use depending on *how* it's used.

Comment: Most things on the site are Creative Commons, but you would need to ensure that the logos were.

Comment: I wasn't asking if it was allowed for the OP to use the logo, but if the designer is allowed to give it to him.